# 「ここで漫画読んでっから」=「ここで漫画読んでいるから」?

Tags: grammar, contractions

『ジョジョの奇妙な冒険』

> ハイジャッカー：こんな後ろにいるんじゃねぇ、前へ行け！
>
> ジョジョ：ハイジャックされたのはスピードワゴンの爺さんだろう。一緒にいただけの僕には関係ないね。**ここで漫画読んでっから**、いいから、気にせず勝手にやってくれ。

My understanding is 「ここで漫画読んでっから」=「ここで漫画読んでいるから」, but what is this construction? Is it limited to 「から」?

Comment: Energy conservation.  Like the コンビニ thanks : ありがssssssss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct. This corruption also happens commonly before と and か, and less commonly, ぞ:

- **読んでっと** ← 読んでると ← 読んでいると
  <sub>(and 見てっと, 寝てっと, 飛んでっと, 笑ってっと, ...)</sub>
- **読んでっか** ← 読んでるか ← 読んでいるか
- **読んでっぞ** ← 読んでるぞ ← 読んでいるぞ

Although rare, 読んでっとき, 読んでっところ and so on may be used, too. I think I have not seen 読んでっわ, 読んでっさ, 読んでっね, 読んでっより, 読んでっため, 読んでっようだ and such.

<sub>This way of speech sounds like Goku in Dragon Ball to me. Maybe Kanto or northern dialect? I grew up in western Japan, and there were no people around me who spoke this way, but I don't think this is purely fictional, either...</sub>

Comment: `読んでっね`と`読んでっより`は何よりもまず発音しにくいです