# Vて+くっから meaning? [3-gatsu no lion episode 1]

Tags: grammar, contractions

I'm confused specifically about what it means, whether it's a dialect-specific thing / commonly used, and when to use it. Here are the sentences I am confused about and their translations from the anime:

んじゃあちょっくら届けてくっからよ

"Well, I'm off to deliver all this."

そのまま宴会に参加してくっから後はよろしくなじゃあ

"After that, I'm staying for the party, so take care of everything else. Bye!"

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's the same contraction as [「ここで漫画読んでっから」=「ここで漫画読んでいるから」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/89055)

Comment: @sundowner In this case, I think it's a contraction of くるから → くっから, whereas the linked question refers to ～ているから → ～てっから. I do agree they're very similar but I wouldn't say they're the exact same contration.

Comment: @GuiImamura As explained in the linked answer, it should be reasonable to think there are two steps: ているから→てるから→てっから. As such, I regard them as instances of る→っ.

Answer (score 2):

That is a contraction of the verb くる when it comes right before から, か or と, just like in this [answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/89061/10627) to the question referred by @sundowner.

`くるから` → `くっから`